# CSSセレクタのh1 + *[rel=up]の意味が分かりません

Tags: css

## CSSセレクタ h1 + *[rel=up] の意味が分かりません

W3C Recommendationの
[6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)

で示されているサンプルコード内の記述なのですが、

```
h1 + *[rel=up]
```

の意味が分かりません。

h1はタイプセレクタ、
+記号は「その直後の」という意味であっていると思うのですが、その次の記述
*(アスタリスク)は何を意味しているのでしょうか。

属性セレクタ[]内で[rel*=style]のような使われ方では文字列の部分一致を意味するそうですが
今回の例では[]の外側、前に位置しており、このケースではどういった意味になるのでしょうか。

何卒ご教授願います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ユニバーサルセレクター](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#universal-selector)ですね。あらゆる HTML 要素がマッチします。

> The universal selector, written "*", matches the name of any element type. It matches any single element in the document tree.

つまり、例の

```
h1 + *[rel=up]
```

は `h1` の直後に続く要素で、`rel` 属性が `up` であるものは、「どんな要素でも」マッチ。